# Upload file form in CP - create module

Tags: control-panel, file-uploads, module, image

I need put in my CP a upload image field.
I would like know if have a possibility that integration of use in my module the default upload file of EE or if I have that do the upload file manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the api to add a single upload field to your module or fieldtype. http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/file_field.html . if you want to include multiple image uploads in the same field, then you will need to do something else.